# Function will not return anything

Tags: c#, forms, function, unit-testing

Unit testing a function but the function isn't returning anything when I run the `unit test`.

This is the function:

```
    public string FindUniqueWords(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary)
    {
        string uniqueWord = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in dictionary) //loop through the occurenceDictionary
        {
            uniqueWord += (pair.Key + ", ");
        }
        uniqueWords.Text = uniqueWord;
        return (uniqueWord);
    }
```

And this is the unit test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckUniqueWordsAreFoundTest()
    {
        string actual, expected;
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        actual = frm1.FindUniqueWords(unitTestOccurenceDictionary);
        expected = "hello, world, i, am, god, of, this, ";
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

And I am sending this dictionary to the function

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> unitTestOccurenceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        unitTestOccurenceDictionary.Add("hello", 1);
        unitTestOccurenceDictionary.Add("world", 2);
        unitTestOccurenceDictionary.Add("I", 1);
        unitTestOccurenceDictionary.Add("am", 1);
        unitTestOccurenceDictionary.Add("god", 1);
        unitTestOccurenceDictionary.Add("of", 1);
        unitTestOccurenceDictionary.Add("this", 1);
    }
```

When I run the unit test it fails and shows that

```
actual = <>
```

I am not sure what is causing this but I feel like it's a stupidly simple mistake like a missing reference but there are no errors when I run my code.

Comment: In your function it appends `,` followed by space for every word (including last word).  So expected output will be "hello, world, i, am, god, of, this, ".

Comment: Where are you calling `Add`? Based on what I can see the dictionary will be empty causing the output to be the empty string. There are other problems, but this would be reason for an empty `actual`. Dictionary is not ordered so there is no guarantee you will get the items in the order they were added.

Comment: what's the purpose of int value in `Dictionary<string, int>`. i think you can use `List<string>` instead of  `Dictionary<string, int>`

Comment: You do know that the order of iterating the elements of a dictionary is indeterminate, so your test could fail at any time in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike spotted my problem in that I wasn't calling the Add function so my dictionary was empty I have since amended my code to this

```
    public Dictionary<string, int> unitTestOccurenceDictionary
        = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
            {"hello", 1},
            {"world", 2},
            {"i", 1},
            {"am", 1},
            {"god", 1},
            {"of", 1},
            {"this", 1}};

    public Dictionary<string, int> unitTestLengthDictionary
        = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
            {"hello", 5},
            {"world", 5},
            {"i", 1},
            {"am", 2},
            {"god", 3},
            {"of", 2},
            {"this", 4}};
```

And it works correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be simply that Dictionary does not guarantee an order of its items.

Try altering your FindUniqueWords function like this to enforce an order on the returned items:

```
string uniqueWord = "";
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    result.Add(key);
}
var uniqueWord = String.Join(", ", result);
return uniqueWord;
```

Then you can change your unit test to expect an ordered result:

```
var expected = "am, god, hello, I, of, this, world";
```

and the test should start passing.

Note: several others mentioned that you also have problems with a ", " at the end of the string, which prompted me to use `String.Join`.  Props to @paxdiablo and @trungtin1710 and @HariPrasad for spotting this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, the statement `uniqueWord += (pair.Key + ", ");` will add each key *and* a comma/space pair to the resultant string.

Hence what would *actually* come out of the function (but see below on ordering) would be:

```
"hello, world, i, am, god, of, this, "
```

The way to fix this is to simply insert into your function, immediately after the `for` loop, something like:

```
char trimChars[] = {',', ' '};
uniqueword = uniqueword.TrimEnd(trimChars);
```

to remove the offending characters at the end.

---

Your second problem appears to be that your dictionary is empty since you state that `actual = <>` by which I assume you mean the empty string.

If that's the case then you need to investigate why the dictionary is not being populated, most likely it's because you're never calling `UnitTest1.Add`.

---

The third problem is to do with, as per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The order of the keys in the Dictionary.KeyCollection is unspecified ...

Hence you can't be certain that the words will come out in the order you expect.

This issue is a little trickier but can be done as well. First step is to modify the string so that *every* word is once again followed by the delimiter:

```
actual = actual + ", ";
```

Then go through the string *removing* each word in turn using, for example:

```
actual = Regex("hello, ").Replace(actual,"",1);
actual = Regex("world, ").Replace(actual,"",1);
actual = Regex("i, ").Replace(actual,"",1);
actual = Regex("am, ").Replace(actual,"",1);
actual = Regex("god, ").Replace(actual,"",1);
actual = Regex("of, ").Replace(actual,"",1);
actual = Regex("this, ").Replace(actual,"",1);
```

and you should then end up with an empty string:

```
Assert.AreEqual("", actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected result is

```
expected = "hello, world, i, am, god, of, this";
```

buy depend on your code, the actual result will look like this

```
actual = "hello, world, I, am, got, of, this, "
```

Note : when unit test be failed, it will throw exception include what are different between actual and expected result